# How to automate build process in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, build

I have a Visual Studio solution that contains several projects grouped within multiple "virtual" folders.  Due to the way the solution is organized, I need to build the projects in a specific order for the project to work correctly.  Right now I need to right-click on the projects in a particular order to do this.

Is there a way I can either make a batch file or (even better) a plug-in that I can add to the toolbar that would do this for me automatically?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is built in to Visual Studio via project dependencies. Essentially you define which projects depend on others and then VS will automatically build them in the correct order.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/et61xzb3(v=vs.100).aspx for details.

Comment: I see some items being checked, others with a grey box, and others with a white box.  What do the grey boxes mean?